# Multithreading in C++ with embedded python modules

Tags: python, c++, gil, python-2.4

I'm trying to create a multi threaded program by launching a boost thread which calls a function which in turn calls some python module but the program hangs there as it acquires some PyGILState_Ensure() lock and waits for it to release indefinitely.Can you please tell me what is wrong here.

Yeah actually a python module calls my c++ code which calls another python module in separate threads , thats why I think its waiting for PyGIL to release which results in deadlock , so , is there any solution to it with using the patch for removing PyGIL?

Answer (score 3):

The Python interpreter isn't re-entrant and needs to lock the interpreter while it's being called (see e.g. http://dabeaz.blogspot.be/2011/08/inside-look-at-gil-removal-patch-of.html).  In your particular situation it seems like there's another Python call on the interpreter already running, and it's holding the GIL.

Comment: Yeah actually a python module calls my c++ code which calls another python module in separate threads , thats why I think its waiting for PyGIL to release which results in deadlock , so , is there any solution to it with using the patch for removing PyGIL?